# RegEx to find ".php" but not when paired with "share.php"

Tags: regex

I am trying to match the string ".php" but only when "share" is not in front of the ".php".  So, for example, "test.php" should be found, but "share.php" should be skipped.

I have this RegEx but it seems to not be working when I think it should.  I think the "." is what is messing me up.

```
(?!.*share)\.php
```

Can anyone give some assistance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your negative lookbehind assertion is incorrectly framed. The following should work

```
(?<!share)\.php
```

Comment: I just tried this code on "test.php" and "share.php" and neither were matched.  test.php should have been matched, no?  but, it does seem to work if you drop the code in here:  http://www.rubular.com/r/faLGlVEDjP  Odd.  Maybe something is wrong with the regex checker in Visual Studio??

Comment: @Dennis, what language are you using? It worked for me, take a look at http://www.rubular.com/r/vq9fVIpNvt

Comment: Yeah, i see that.  Odd it is not working in Visual Studio?!  I am using it to find code chunks in a project and the share.php exists on hundreds of pages, but other links with anything.php are very few.  Was hoping not to have to brute-force it!! :(

Comment: @Dennis, per http://stackoverflow.com/q/9022258/753731, Visual Studio supports non-standard regex syntax, you may want to look at the accepted answer there. I have no means of testing it.

Answer (score 2):

**These are 100% confirmed working solutions:**

If you are using Visual Studio, this is the code to achieve this:

```
~(share)\.php
```

If you are just looking for a typical RegEx (not with Visual Studio), this works:

```
(?<!share)\.php
```

Thanks for the input all!

Dennis

Comment: You did not need to post it as an answer. Completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to use a negative lookahead. Correct regex for that case would be:

```
^(?!share)[^.]+\.php$
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/wFmMH8E2WI

**Using lookbehind:**

```
^[^.]+(?<!share)\.php$
```

Answer (score -2):

```
[^(share)]\.php
```

how about that?

Alternative if you are using grep

```
ls | grep \.php$ | grep -v share\.php
```

Comment: This is wrong. You regex will check for each character in "share"; even "s.php" will not be recognized. What you need is a negative lookbehind.