# Regex look behind in VS Code?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, regex-lookarounds, vscode-extensions

I'm working on a grammar extension in VS Code, and I'm having difficulty with a look behind regex pattern. Given the following string, I want to only return **cmp** when it's preceded by the **@fmt(**

```
@fmt(cmp,foo)
```

The matching string I used in another editor was this:

```
(?<=[@|©](fmt)\()(\w+)
```

However, this is not working in VS Code, when I do a regex search it comes back with the error that it's not a valid expression. Playing around with it, the problem is the **<=** characters, which indicate the look behind.

Doing a search of the VS Code website doesn't return any kind of regex reference guide. Searching Stack Overflow came up with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022258/in-visual-studio-2010-how-do-you-search-for-text-that-is-not-within-a-single-li), which states that Visual Studio has a unique regex definitions. Unfortunately, the example given in that question doesn't work in VS Code.

Does anyone know how to do a look behind regex in VS Code? Or at least know where the regex documentation for VS Code is located?

I worry that it's not possible, since according to [Stack Overflow reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075) look behinds aren't supported in JavaScript. There is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35142364/regex-negative-lookbehind-not-valid-in-javascript/35143111#35143111) that shows how to mimic look behinds in a JavaScript function, but I don't know if it's possible to extend a language in VS Code with user-defined functions. If anyone knows how to do that, and can point me in that direction, that would also be an acceptable workaround.

Comment: Thomas, what are you doing? Please explain what you need to do with `@fmt(cmp,foo)`? What is the final result? Find & highlight? Then you do not need the lookbehind at all, nor capturing groups - `[@©]fmt\(\w+` will be enough.

Comment: It's for syntax highlighting, I want the **@fmt** to be one color (function), and the **cmp** to be another color (parameter). There are multiple possible strings following the @ symbols, this was just a simplified example.

Comment: I do have the **@fmt** portion working using the string **([@|©|®]\w+)**. I was just stumped with having the parameter inside the parentheses as a different color, which as I stated in the question I have working in my Editpad Pro syntax coloring.

Comment: Syntax highlighting in VSCode does not use JavaScript regexes, but the Oniguruma library (since it's based on syntax highlighting grammars from the TextMate editor, which uses Oniguruma), see [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#textmate-grammars)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**You *can use `infinite-width lookahead and lookbehind`* without any constraint now beginning with Visual Studio Code v.1.31.0 release**.

See proof:

[image]

and another one (with `(?<=@fmt\([^()]*)\w+` pattern, note the `*` in the lookbehind):

[image]

See the [Github *`[VSCode 1.31] ES2018 RegExp lookbehind assertions are now supported #68004`* issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/68004):

> As a result of moving to **Electron 3.0**, `RegExp` lookbehind assertions are now supported, since they’re supported since **Chromium 62** and **Node 8.10.0**, and **Electron 3.0** uses **Chromium 66** and **Node 10.2.0**, so they’re now supported, but the release notes don’t mention that lookbehind assertions are now supported.

VS Code developers [confirm that it is true](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/68004#issuecomment-461205786) that they "forgot to mention it in the release notes".

**Note that variable-length lookbehind assertions will only work in the file editor search, but not in the *`Find in Files`* search (the magnifying glass icon)**. According to [this GitHub issue discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/143453#issuecomment-1048139108),

> Search in the editor uses the JS regex engine, and search across files uses [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) which doesn't support [variable-length lookbehind assertions]. There are a small number of differences in regex feature support, this is one of them.

See these closed issues in the `ripgrep` repo:

- [Regexp expression failure when using lookbehind](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/issues/644)
- [allow handling lookbehind assertions of non-fixed length](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/issues/1025)

Answer (score 5):

## Update

**Visual Studio Code v.1.31.0 and up have regex lookbehind support, see  [Wiktor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57868396/10972414)**

---

Visual Studio code uses JavaScript's regular expressions as specified in ECMAScript 5, which doesn't support look behinds (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/8635).

Here's a workaround you can try if you're doing find and replace (thanks cyborgx37):

Search Expression:

`(lookbehind_expression_)text_to_replace`

Replace Expression:

`$1replacement_text`

Given the input:

`lookbehind_expression_text_to_replace`

The output will be:

`lookbehind_expression_replacement_text`

Comment: This answer is outdated, please check [Wiktor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57868396/10972414)

Answer (score -1):

Look ahead and look behind both work in VS Code. Download some of the existing language plugins and look at their rules, to learn how this must be formulated. Here's a part from my ANTLR grammar extension:

```
{
  "name": "meta.rule.parser.antlr",
  "begin": "[[:lower:]][[:alnum:]_]*(?=.*?:)",
  "beginCaptures": {
    "0": { "name": "entity.name.function.parser.antlr" }
  },
  "end": "(?<=;)",
  "patterns": [
    {
      "name": "variable.other",
      "match": "\\[.*?\\]"
    },
    {
      "name": "keyword.other.antlr",
      "match": "\\b(returns|locals)\\b"
    },
    {
      "name": "keyword.other.antlr",
      "match": "@\\w+"
    },
    {
      "name": "entity.other.rule.option",
      "match":" <.*?>"
    },
    {
      "name": "variable.other.antlr",
      "match": "\\w+\\s*="
    },
    {
      "name": "entity.name.tag.antlr",
      "match": "#.*"
    },

    { "include": "#comments" },
    { "include": "#strings" },
    { "include": "#lexer-rule-reference" },
    { "include": "#parser-rule-reference" },
    { "include": "#predicate" },
    { "include": "#action" },
    { "include": "#wildcard-regexp" },
    { "include": "#regexp-parts" },
    { "include": "#options-list" }

  ]
}
```

The end match uses a look behind pattern. Keep also in mind you can nest patterns, i.e. you can define begin/end for a bigger structure (e.g. an entire function) and then match parts of it with sub patterns (and assign the individual style). This why you often don't need look ahead/behind because you know you are in a certain block of code.

For your pattern above: is the `(\w+)` part supposed to be part of the lookbehind pattern? If so it should be before the last closing parenthesis.

Comment: I tried the `(?<=)` syntax, still getting an invalid regular expression / invalid group error. It seems like VS code doesn't support back references: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/8635

Comment: Your lookarounds are all lookaheads, not lookbehinds.

Comment: `(?=` is a positive lookahead, while `(?<=` is a positive lookbehind.