# match but don't select with regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to capture the term `ISomething` only when it isn't immediately  preceded by a full stop `.` however my search is capturing the preceding letter or space. I'm using javascript style regex (vscode search to be exact).

My aim is to replace `ISomething` with `Namespace.ISomething` without touching existing namespaces.

[Live example](https://regexr.com/3ini7)

My search sample

```
Api.Resources.Things.Bits.ISomething     //doesn't match
something : ISomething
List<ISomething>
something:ISomething
isomething                               //doesn't match
```

My regex

```
[^\.](ISomething)
```

My matches, the first captures the whitespace, the second the arrow, third the bracket.

```
  ISomething
 <ISomething
 :ISomething
```

How (and why) can i just get the word `ISomething` in all of the above?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want to achieve: replace `ISomething` with something else? Then use `(^|[^.])ISomething` and replace with `$1` to remove those instances. Or replace with `$1NEW STRING` to replace with a new string.

Comment: My aim is to replace ISomething with Namespace.ISomething without touching existing namespaces.

Comment: So, you may try [`(^|[^.])\b(ISomething)\b` to replace with `$1Namespace.$2`](https://regex101.com/r/v5c5mY/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## UPDATE

**You [can use infinite-width lookahead and lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57868396/3832970) without any constraint beginning with Visual Studio Code v.1.31.0 release, and you do not need to set any options for that now.**

So, the solution can look like

**Find what**: `\b(?<!\.)ISomething\b`
**Replace with**: `Namespace.$&`

[image]

The `(?<!\.)` must be after `\b` for better performance (in order not to perform lookbehind check at each position in a string) and is a *negative lookbehind* that matches a position that is not immediately preceded with a literal `.`. The `$&` in the replacement is a whole match value backreference/placeholder.

## With older versions you may use

**Find what**: `(^|[^.])\b(ISomething)\b`
**Replace with**: `$1Namespace.$2`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v5c5mY/1/) and the VSCode settings below:

[image]

NOTE that the `Aa` (case sensitivity) and `.*` (regex mode) options must be ON.

After clicking *Replace all*, the results are:

[image]

**Regex details**

- `(^|[^.])` - Group 1: either the start of the line/string or any char other than `.`
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(ISomething)` - Group 2: the word `ISomething`
- `\b` - a word boundary

Comment: This works! I wasn't expecting it to because I didn't understand how the `$1` related to match groups. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if supported `\K` may be what you are looking for:

```
[^\.]\KISomething
```

Comment: I think this only works with PERL regex, but thanks I still learned something new :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a negative lookbehind

`(?<!\.)ISomething` basically this will match any ISomething that is not preceded by a `.`