# Visual Studio Code - Regex Insert digit between digits

Tags: regex, replace, visual-studio-code, digits

I want to add "0" at position 7

```
010101001
010101002
010101003
010101004
```

and make it look like this

```
0101010001
0101010002
0101010003
0101010004
```

I am using this regex :

```
(0[1-9]0[1-9]0[1-9]0[0-9][1-9])
```

It finds all strings of this pattern but I don't know how to point it to position 7 , like {7} but how to use it

Thanks

Comment: please explain well so we could help you.

Comment: Here is a string
["01","0101","010101","010101001","010102","010103","010104","010105","010105001","010106","010106001","010106002","010106003","01"]

convert
010105001 to 0101050001

Comment: Its in Visual Studio Code text editor hope it will help you understand the situation.

Comment: so you want  to replace string search from file in code editor right?

Comment: I have tried this (?<=^\d{6})  in code editor and its not helping the situation, may there is a different method in VS Code.

Comment: @ZeeshanTariq Try finding `^(\d{6})` and replacing with `${1}0`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow !!

Comment: Try `(?<=^\d{6})` and replace with `0` in the *current* VSCode release. It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

We can try matching the pattern `(?<=\d{6})` and replacing with zero.  The idea here is to lookbehind the string and insert zero at the seventh position, which occurs when we see six digits behind the current point.

```
Dim input as string = "010101004"
Dim output as string = Regex.Replace(input, "(?<=^\d{6})", "0")
Console.WriteLine(output)

0101010004
```

### Demo

Comment: i am using vs code find and replace in multiple files.

Comment: @ZeeshanTariq Then your question was misleading, or maybe I misread it.  You should still be able to find `(?<=^\d{6})` and replace with `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be specific that you only want to look at 9 digit numbers.
If you don't do that, it turns into a rats nest of ambiguity.

Use assertion to insure only 9 digit numbers are looked at.

Based on you're regex, I suggest using this.

Find `(?<!\d)((?:0[1-9]){3})(0[0-9][1-9])(?!\d)`
Replace `${1}0${2}`

Formatted

```
 (?<! \d )                     # Not a digit behind
 (                             # (1 start), first 6 qualified digits
      (?: 0 [1-9] ){3}
 )                             # (1 end)
 ( 0 [0-9] [1-9] )             # (2), last 3 qualified digits
 (?! \d )                      # Not a digit ahead
```

Answer (score 0):

You [can use infinite-width lookahead and lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57868396/3832970) without any constraint beginning with Visual Studio Code v.1.31.0 release, and you do not need to set any options for that now.

**Find What**:     `(?<=^\d{6})`
**Replace With**: `0`

Proof & test:

[image]