# Lazy Regex before lookahead : not working with `.+?`

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, regex-lookarounds

I am using VS Code. And I want to select all matches in `italics` preceding `{:term}`. Unfortunately VS code doesn't support lookbehind yet, so I am content with the first *.

Pattern: `\*.+?(?=\*\{\:term\})`

Contents:

```
    * *Pivot Row*{:term}
This is another term *Pivot Row*{:term}
* **List**: This is another term *Pivot Row*{:term}
*This* is *another* term repetition *Pivot Row*{:term}
```

Desired Selected Output:

```
*Pivot Row
*Pivot Row
*Pivot Row
*Pivot Row
```

But the  following gets selected:

```
* *Pivot Row
*Pivot Row
* **List**: This is another term *Pivot Row
*This* is *another* term repetition *Pivot Row
```

Could you please suggest changes to the pattern?

Also, could you please explain why the lazy dot doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may replace the [lazy dot](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution) (`.+?`) with a greedily quantified [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^*]*`:

```
\*[^*]*(?=\*\{:term})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oGfzcg/1).

**NOTE**: Note that starting with [VSCode 1.29](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_29#_backreferences-and-lookahead-in-search), you need to [enable `search.usePCRE2` option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52150634/3832970) to enable lookaheads in your regex patterns.

**NOTE2:** You [can use infinite-width lookahead and lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57868396/3832970) without any constraint beginning with Visual Studio Code v.1.31.0 release, and you do not need to set any PCRE2 option now.

Note that `.` matches any char but a line break char, hence, it can match a `*` char, too. Since the regex engine searches for matches from left to right, and starts matching beginning with the leftmost occurrence, the first `*` char on the lines got matched with the first `\*` pattern and `.+?` matched as few chars as necessary to complete a valid match, "gobbling up" all `*` symbols on its way to `*{:term}`.

**Details**

- `\*` - a `*` char
- `[^*]*` - 0+ chars other than `*`, as many as possible
- `(?=\*\{:term})` - a positive lookahead that requires `*{:term}` substring to appear immediately to the right of the current location.

Note that `}` and `:` are not special and do not have to be escaped.

Comment: Could you please explain why the lazy dot doesn't work?

Comment: @Nikhil I was writing the explanation when you were writing the comment :)