# Regex: match and replace spaces only in particular lines

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I'm sure I'll bang my head against the wall when I read the answer, but I can't figure this one out.

I have a JSON with fake data to populate a db. One property is called "slug" and contains a string that I'd like to "slugify".

So this:

```
[
  {
    blah: '[...]'
    slug: 'Plem ap at rem',
    bleh: '[...]',
  },
  {
    blah: '[...]'
    slug: 'Etiam vel augue',
    bleh: '[...]',
  },
]
```

Should become:

```
[
  {
    blah: '[...]'
    slug: 'Plem-ap-at-rem',
    bleh: '[...]',
  },
  {
    blah: '[...]'
    slug: 'Etiam-vel-augue',
    bleh: '[...]',
  },
]
```

I wanted to first target the value and hopelessly capture only the spaces:

```
slug: '(?:[\w]*([\s])*)+'
```

I've messed a bit with lookarounds but no luck.

PS: I intend to use it in the VSCode's find&replace, but knowing how would I do this in **plain JS** is welcome too!

Comment: Not possible in VSC but Notepad++ or Sublime Text would be a solution. Like this `(?:slug\W+|\G(?!^))\K(\w+) +`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/VVBGhW/1

Comment: It's a shame that one doesn't work in js :(

Comment: In plain JS it would be easy but unfortunately no way in VSC.

Comment: @revo How'd it be in js then?

Answer (score 4):

You [can use infinite-width lookahead and lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57868396/3832970) without any constraint beginning with Visual Studio Code v.1.31.0 release.

You may use

**Find What**:     `(?<=slug: '[^']*)\s`
**Replace With**: `-`

**Details**

- `(?<=slug: '[^']*)` - a location in a string that is immediately preceded with `slug:`, space, `'` and 0+ chars other than `'`
- `\s` - one whitespace.

See a demo screenshot:

[image]

Since you asked how this can be done in JavaScript:

```js
const text = `[\n      {\n        blah: '[...]'\n        slug: 'Plem ap at rem',\n        bleh: '[...]',\n      },\n      {\n        blah: '[...]'\n        slug: 'Etiam vel augue',\n        bleh: '[...]',\n      },\n    ]`;
console.log(text.replace(/(?<=slug: '[^']*)\s/gi, '-'))
```

Or, if you are using Safari or any other JS environment that does not support ECMAScript 2018 standard:

```js
const text = `[\n      {\n        blah: '[...]'\n        slug: 'Plem ap at rem',\n        bleh: '[...]',\n      },\n      {\n        blah: '[...]'\n        slug: 'Etiam vel augue',\n        bleh: '[...]',\n      },\n    ]`;
console.log(text.replace(/(slug:\s*')([^']*)/gi, function(m,x,y) { 
  return x + y.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
}));
```

Comment: That's helpful to know. So, at http://regex101,com, we should select JavaScript to test these expressions.

Answer (score -2):

UPDATE: Look behinds now supported in VSCode, see Wiktor's answer & [vscode/issues/68004](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/68004)

---

Simple, but rather clunky alternative:

`(slug: '\S*)\s` replace with: `$1-`

You'll have to spam click the Replace All button a few times until the match count has gone down to 0 since it only matches the first occurrence on each line. Not ideal I know but if you're just doing it once...

Comment: This answer is obsolete as lookbehinds work in VSCode.