# Finding and replacing key: value pairs

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm in the process of porting over a Python library to JavaScript / TypeScript. To help myself out, I'm trying to develop various regex rules that I can apply to files that will automatically convert a lot of the syntax and at least get me close, cleaning up where needed.

I've got the following example:

https://regex101.com/r/mIr0pl/1

```
this.mk(attrs={keyCollection.key: 40}))
this.mk(attrs={keyCollection.key: 50, override.key: override.value})
this.mk(attrs={keyCollection.key: 60, 
               override.key: override.value})
```

I am trying to do a Find/Replace in my editor, to find all `key: value` pairs associated with `attrs` dictionaries. Here's the regex I've got:

`/attrs={(.+?):\s*(.+?)}/gms`

I want to convert it to this:

```
this.mk(attrs=[[keyCollection.key, 40]]))
this.mk(attrs=[[keyCollection.key, 50], [override.key, override.value]])
this.mk(attrs=[[keyCollection.key, 60], 
               [override.key, override.value]])
```

I'm having trouble first nailing down the regex to get the repeated key: value groups, and then also how I would go about utilizing those repeated groups in a replace.

(my editor is VSCode, but I'm using this nifty extension to run these modifications: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bhughes339.replacerules)

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Do `[[` and `]]` uniquely appear with `attrs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since VS Code already [supports infinite-width lookbehind construct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57868396/3832970) you may use

```
"replacerules.rules": {
    "Wrap the attrs with square brackets first": {
        "find": "(attrs=){([^:{]+:*[^}]*)}",
        "replace": "$1[[$2]]"
    },
    "Format attributes inside attrs": {
        "find": "(?<=attrs=\\[\\[[^\\]]*(?:](?!])[^\\]]*)*),(\\s*)",
        "replace": "],$1["
    },
    "Replace colons with commas inside attrs": {
        "find": "(?<=attrs=\\[\\[[^\\]]*(?:](?!])[^\\]]*)*):",
        "replace": ","
    }
}

"replacerules.rulesets": {
    "Revamp attrs": {
        "rules": [
            "Wrap the attrs with square brackets first",
            "Format attributes inside attrs",
            "Replace colons with commas inside attrs"
        ]
    }
}
```

[Step #1 regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DnjWaD/1)

[Step #2 regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DnjWaD/2)

[Step #3 regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DnjWaD/3)

Output:

```
this.mk(attrs=[[keyCollection.key, 40]]))
this.mk(attrs=[[keyCollection.key, 50], [override.key, override.value]])
this.mk(attrs=[[keyCollection.key, 60], 
               [override.key, override.value]])
```

Comment: This was very informative, exactly what I needed, and includes the config for ReplaceRules too! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,

```
(?<=attrs={|,)([^:}]*):([^:},]*)(?=}|,)
```

might be somehow closer.

If you might have had other `attrs`, you might want to initially filter out those others.

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/5rcTFy/1). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/5rcTFy/1debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: I never knew about the regex debugger, thats nifty! Thanks for the info!