# How to replace all whitespace between quotes that start with specific string with underscore in VSCode?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have the following string:

```
this is a sample id="aaa bbb ccc" name="abc abc"
```

I want to match only the whitespace between quotes that start with the string "id=" and replace all occurrences with underscore. The result string should look like:

```
this is a sample id="aaa_bbb_ccc" name="abc abc"
```

The following regex matches all whitespace between quotes, but it doesn't take into account the fact that the quotes must be preceded by "id="

```
\s(?=[^"]*"[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)
```

Quotes inside quotes are not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since starting with VS Code 1.31, [infinite-width lookbehinds are supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57868396/3832970),  you may use

```
(?<=\bid="[^"]*?)\s
```

Or, to make sure there actually *is* a `"` after the whitespace,

```
(?<=\bid="[^"]*?)\s(?=[^"]*")
```

Replace with `_`.

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/DyBsRf/1). Details:

- `(?<=\bid="[^"]*?)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with

  - `\b` - word boundary
  - `id="` - a literal `id="` string
  - `[^"]*?` - any 0 or more chars other than `"`, as few as possible (due to `*?` non-greedy quantifier)
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `(?=[^"]*")` - a positive lookahead that matches a location immediately followed with any 0+ chars other than `"` (with `[^"]*` pattern) and then a `"`.

See the proof it works in VSCode:

[image]